# Do suspended generator functions have performance costs?

Tags: javascript, function, generator

Does a perpetually suspended function generator have performance costs?

For example, the code below will continually `yield` values until the value of `d` in the `for` loop is reached.

For the purposes of the question, we intentionally prevent the generator from reaching the status of `done`. Is there a resource cost in doing this? It would, of course, theoretically be easy to indicate to the generator that we are in fact `done` with it, but does it even matter? Why not just have it eternally suspended until it needs to be used again?

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'strawberry']

function* fruitGenerator(items) {
  var numberOfItems = items.length
  var i = 0

  while (true) {
    yield items[i]
    i++
    if (i === numberOfItems) {
      i = 0
    }
  }
}

var multipleFruits = fruitGenerator(fruits)

for (var d = 0 ; d < 10; d++) {
  console.log(multipleFruits.next())
}
```

For all intents and purposes, let's just assume that for this example, I cannot use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: *"For all intents and purposes, let's just assume that for this example"* - isn't "for *this* example" the opposite of "for *all* intents and purposes"? Anyway, any generator function *may* never be done if it isn't called much, even if it hasn't been deliberately coded to loop infinitely - I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "performance cost". Memory size, speed? And compared to what - ending and re-instantiating the generator?

Comment: By performance cost, I mean memory size AND speed. Is it generator function as fast as a standard `for` loop? Is it slower still than `forEach`? Does a suspended generator get stored in memory whilst it's waiting to be reinvoked? Is it more memory efficient to end the generator and re-instantiate again later if needed?

Comment: @Modermo When you have a lot of suspended generator objects laying around they indeed consume additional memory. But it is the same with exhausted generators. There is no difference. And as soon as there is no reference pointing to a generator, it is GCed as any other object, no matter if it is exhausted or suspended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generator functions have their own execution context which must be restored each time a generator function is [resumed](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-generatorresume). When a generator function is not being executed, its execution context is stored in an internal property slot, `[[GeneratorContext]]`, of the geerator object.

In the sense are there **any overheads whatsoever** in using generator functions, the answer is yes, there are they those required to restore a saved execution. Would you be able to detect them using profiling tools, probably not - all JavaScript operations have execution steps defined in standards, and restoring and saving execution contexts is unlikely to be more significant than other steps in JavaScript operation.

In the sense do generator functions consume execution time when not being used, the asnwer is no. [Generator objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) are objects residing in memory until used.